# Problema ao apagar um campo da tabela

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

Quando tento apagar uma linha da minha tabela, ele me retorna esse erro

`ERROR:  update or delete on table "menu" violates foreign key constraint "fk_menu_id" on table "view_menu"
DETAIL:  Key (menu_id)=(2370) is still referenced from table "view_menu".`

O que seria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está dizendo que a linha em questão possui informações vinculadas na tabela `view_menu`, apague primeiro o que está vinculado na tabela `view_menu` para que possa apagar da tabela `menu`